# Automatically list Sundays in a month with prefixs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am making a rota for a group on Sunday evenings and I thought I would mess around a little to see if I could automate the listing of the dates. I eventually either made or found a solution to almost everything. The only problem I have now is that I need two cells to show the date of the Sunday with prefixes instead of one.

The table currently looks like this

[image: Two Columns]

Whereas I would like it to look like this

[image: Single Column]

I have a link of an online Microsoft Office Excel Book [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AAC4FF215312539A!2964&authkey=!AMNRgU8iaLYGONg&ithint=file%2cxlsx) (Its editable)

Currently I am using formula such as

```
=DATE(YEAR($B$3), MONTH($B$3), MOD(7-DATE(YEAR($B$3), MONTH($B$3), 1)+ 1,7)+1) //For the first Sunday of the month
=DAY(DATE(YEAR($B$3), MONTH($B$3), MOD(7-DATE(YEAR($B$3), MONTH($B$3), 1)+ 1,7)+1))&VLOOKUP(DAY(DATE(YEAR($B$3), MONTH($B$3), MOD(7-DATE(YEAR($B$3), MONTH($B$3), 1)+ 1,7)+1)),$E$4:$F$12,2,TRUE) //For the first Sunday of the month with a prefix

=IF(YEAR(B4+7)>$B$3,"",B4+7) //Subsequent Sundays
=DAY(IF(YEAR(B4+7)>$B$3,"",B4+7))&VLOOKUP(DAY(IF(YEAR(B4+7)>$B$3,"",B4+7)),$E$4:$F$12,2,TRUE) //Subsequent Sundays with Prefix
```

I would appreciate any help in achieving this.

Comment: Just change the first column of dates to have a custom number format of `d\t\h`.  It will output the `5th`, but it will also output `1th` and `2th` and `3th` unfortunately.

Comment: @ScottCraner That is why I'm not doing it that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a formula solution, you can do the following.

```
A1:  The first date in any month (e.g. 1-Jun-2016)

A2:  = IF(SUM(INT((EOMONTH($A$1,0)-1)/7)-INT(($A$1-2)/7))>=ROWS($1:1), TEXT($A$1-DAY($A$1)+1+7*ROWS($1:1)-WEEKDAY($A$1-DAY($A$1)),"d")&MID("thstndrdthththththth",1+2*(MOD(TEXT($A$1-DAY($A$1)+1+7*ROWS($1:1)-WEEKDAY($A$1-DAY($A$1)),"d"),10)*(ABS(MOD(TEXT($A$1-DAY($A$1)+1+7*ROWS($1:1)-WEEKDAY($A$1-DAY($A$1)),"d"),100)-12)>1)),2),"")
```

and fill down to A6.  It will auto adjust for months with four vs five Sundays.

The first Sunday in the month is computed by:

```
=A1-DAY(A1)+1+7*ROWS($1:1)-WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1))
```

The `ROWS($1:1)` part is used to increment the date by 7 for the subsequent Sundays.

The number of Sundays in the month, used to determine whether to blank line five, is computed by:

```
=SUM(INT((EOMONTH($A$1,0)-1)/7)-INT(($A$1-2)/7))
```

The rest of the formula is to compute the proper suffix for the date.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much